# Prove $(a^2-b^2)^2\ge4ab(a-b)^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Prove $(a^2-b^2)^2\ge4ab(a-b)^2$

I started to prove this inequality by simplifying both sides and got:
$a^4+6a^2b^2+b^4\ge4a^3b+4ab^3$ but do not see where to go from here

Answer (score 2):

we have $$(a-b)^2\left(a^2+b^2+2ab-4ab\right)\geq 0$$
this is true since we get $$(a-b)^4\geq 0$$

Answer (score 2):

Fill in details and supply justification:

$$(a^2-b^2)^2\ge 4ab(a-b)^2\iff (a-b)^2(a+b)^2\ge4ab(a-b)^2\iff$$

$$(a+b)^2\ge4ab\iff(a-b)^2\ge0$$

Answer (score 0):

For all $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ we have $(a-b)^4\ge0$. Thus
$$
\begin{align*}
(a-b)^4&\ge 0\\
a^4-4a^3b+6a^2b^2-4ab^3+b^4&\ge0\\
a^4+6a^2b^2+b^4&\ge4a^3b+4ab^3\\
(a^2-b^2)^2&\ge 4ab(a^2+b^2).
\end{align*}
$$